While using the table_calendar package in Flutter, the markers are displayed only when a day is clicked
I'm using the table_calendar package in Flutter to display a calendar with event markers. However, the markers are only displayed when a day is clicked. I want the markers to appear for all days with events by default, without needing to click each day.
class CustomCalender extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function(DateTimeRange) updateDateRange;
  const CustomCalender({super.key, required this.updateDateRange});

  @override
  State<CustomCalender> createState() => _CustomCalenderState();
}

class _CustomCalenderState extends State<CustomCalender> {
  final PaymentDao _paymentDao = PaymentDao();

  late final ValueNotifier<List<Payment>> _selectedPayments;
  CalendarFormat _calendarFormat = CalendarFormat.month;
  RangeSelectionMode _rangeSelectionMode = RangeSelectionMode.toggledOn;
  DateTime _focusedDay = DateTime.now();
  DateTime? _selectedDay;
  DateTime? _rangeStart;
  DateTime? _rangeEnd;

  // Cache for payments to use with eventLoader
  final Map<DateTime, List<Payment>> _paymentCache = {};

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _selectedDay = _focusedDay;
    _selectedPayments = ValueNotifier([]);
    _fetchPaymentsForDay(_selectedDay!);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _selectedPayments.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  Future<void> _fetchPaymentsForDay(DateTime day) async {
    final payments = await _paymentDao.find(
      range: DateTimeRange(start: day, end: day),
    );
    setState(() {
      _paymentCache[day] = payments;
      _selectedPayments.value = payments;
    });
  }

  Future<void> _fetchPaymentsForRange(DateTime start, DateTime end) async {
    final payments = await _paymentDao.find(
      range: DateTimeRange(start: start, end: end),
    );
    setState(() {
      // Cache the payments for each day in the range
      for (final payment in payments) {
        final day = DateTime(payment.datetime.year, payment.datetime.month,
            payment.datetime.day);
        if (_paymentCache[day] == null) {
          _paymentCache[day] = [];
        }
        _paymentCache[day]!.add(payment);
      }
      _selectedPayments.value = payments;
    });
  }

  void _onDaySelected(DateTime selectedDay, DateTime focusedDay) {
    if (!isSameDay(_selectedDay, selectedDay)) {
      setState(() {
        _selectedDay = selectedDay;
        _focusedDay = focusedDay;
        _rangeStart = null;
        _rangeEnd = null;
        _rangeSelectionMode = RangeSelectionMode.toggledOff;
      });

      _fetchPaymentsForDay(selectedDay);
    }
  }

  void _onRangeSelected(DateTime? start, DateTime? end, DateTime focusedDay) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedDay = null;
      _focusedDay = focusedDay;
      _rangeStart = start;
      _rangeEnd = end;
      _rangeSelectionMode = RangeSelectionMode.toggledOn;
    });

    if (start != null && end != null) {
      _fetchPaymentsForRange(start, end);
      widget.updateDateRange(DateTimeRange(start: start, end: end));
    } else if (start != null) {
      _fetchPaymentsForDay(start);
    } else if (end != null) {
      _fetchPaymentsForDay(end);
    }
  }

  List<Payment> _getPaymentsForDay(DateTime day) {
    return _paymentCache[day] ?? [];
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Payments'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          TableCalendar<Payment>(
            firstDay: kFirstDay,
            lastDay: kLastDay,
            focusedDay: _focusedDay,
            selectedDayPredicate: (day) => isSameDay(_selectedDay, day),
            rangeStartDay: _rangeStart,
            rangeEndDay: _rangeEnd,
            calendarFormat: _calendarFormat,
            rangeSelectionMode: _rangeSelectionMode,
            eventLoader: _getPaymentsForDay,
            startingDayOfWeek: StartingDayOfWeek.monday,
            calendarStyle: const CalendarStyle(
              outsideDaysVisible: false,
            ),
            onDaySelected: _onDaySelected,
            onRangeSelected: _onRangeSelected,
            onFormatChanged: (format) {
              if (_calendarFormat != format) {
                setState(() {
                  _calendarFormat = format;
                });
              }
            },
            onPageChanged: (focusedDay) {
              _focusedDay = focusedDay;
            },
            calendarBuilders: CalendarBuilders(
              markerBuilder: (context, day, events) {
                if (events.isNotEmpty) {
                  return Positioned(
                    bottom: 0,
                    right: 2.0, // Adjust the right offset as needed
                    child: Container(
                      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.blue,
                        shape: BoxShape.circle,
                      ),
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(
                          6.0), // Adjust padding for increased size
                      child: Center(
                        child: Text(
                          '${events.length}',
                          style: const TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontSize: 14.0, // Adjust font size as needed
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                } else {
                  return const SizedBox();
                }
              },
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 8.0),
          Expanded(
            child: ValueListenableBuilder<List<Payment>>(
              valueListenable: _selectedPayments,
              builder: (context, value, _) {
                return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: value.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return Container(
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        horizontal: 12.0,
                        vertical: 4.0,
                      ),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        border: Border.all(),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
                      ),
                      child: ListTile(
                        title: Text(value[index].title),
                        subtitle: Text('Amount: ${value[index].amount}'),
                        trailing: Text(value[index].type.name),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

// Define constants for the calendar
final kToday = DateTime.now();
final kFirstDay = DateTime(kToday.year, kToday.month - 3, kToday.day);
final kLastDay = DateTime(kToday.year, kToday.month + 3, kToday.day);


the expected output is:

but when loaded the output is:


Use singleMarkerBuilder: (context,date,dynamic){
}
then you can customize the mark event , need to return a widget

Can you use the markup code mode to write code. While this is understandable to the trained eye, beginners might find it hard to understand what you are trying to portray

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
